# Whole code - cinema tickets (in progress)

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my full code (so far). My database, "biografer_test.db", contains: cinema name, total seats, adult price, senior price and kids price. It is currently 3 cinemas in it but it is changeable. My issue is that only the last entry is stored and printed.

| cinema name | seats | adult | senior | kids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sergel | 270 | 140 | 130 | 100 |
| Saga | 250 | 130 | 115 | 95 |
| Soder | 290 | 135 | 120 | 105 |

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.title("Stockholmsbiografer")
import sqlite3 
conn = sqlite3.connect("biografer_test.db")
c = conn.cursor()


class Huvudmeny:
    
    meny_label = Label(root, text="Välkommen till en ny arbetsdag! \n vänligen välj nedan vad du vill göra")
    meny_label.pack()

    def __init__(self, master):
        inramning = Frame(master)
        inramning.pack()
    
        self.alla_biograferknapp= Button(master, text="Välj alla biografer", command=self.allabior)
        self.alla_biograferknapp.pack()
    
        self.avslutaknapp = Button(master, text="Avsluta", command=root.destroy, fg="red")
        self.avslutaknapp.pack()

    
    def allabior(self):
        fonster4=Toplevel()
        fonster4.title("Biljettförsäljning för ALLA biografer.")
        fonster4.geometry("350x200")
        inforuta = Label(fonster4, text="Vänligen skriv in info om alla biografer nedan.")
        inforuta.pack()

        bio1 = [] 

        
        def valj_biograf(fonster, person_typ, text_variabel):
            
            Label(fönster, text=person_typ).pack()
            salda = Entry(fönster, textvariable=text_variabel)
            salda.pack()
            return salda

def skriva_info():
    global bio1

    
    myLabel = Label(fönster4, text=salda.get()).pack()
anslut = sqlite3.connect('biografer_test.db')
c = anslut.cursor()
listvarden = c.execute('SELECT * FROM biografer')
biografnamn = c.fetchall()

BIOGRAFVAL = []
PLATSER = []
#VUXENPRIS = []
#PENSIONÄRSPRIS = []
#BARNPRIS = []

for row in biografnamn:
    biograf = row[0]
    antal_platser = row[1]
    #vpris = row[2]
    #ppris = row[3]
    #bpris = row[4]
    BIOGRAFVAL.append(biograf)
    PLATSER.append(antal_platser)
    #VUXENPRIS.append(vpris)
    #PENSIONÄRSPRIS.append(ppris)
    #BARNPRIS.append(bpris)



i = 0
for elements in BIOGRAFVAL:
    vuxen = StringVar()
    pensionär = StringVar()
    barn = StringVar()

    Label(fonster4, text= BIOGRAFVAL[i]).pack()
    Label(fonster4, text="Skriv in antal biljetter av varje sort du vill köpa").pack()
    Label(fonster4, text="Max antal platser för " + BIOGRAFVAL[i] + " är " + str(PLATSER[i])).pack()
    
    i +=1

    personer = [('vuxen',vuxen),('pensionar', pensionar), ('barn',barn)]

    for p in personer:
        salda1 = välj_biograf(fönster4, p[0] + "biljett", p[1].get())
        salda1.pack()

    

Button(fonster4, text="fortsätt", command=lambda: info()).pack()




def info():
            fonster5=Toplevel()
            fonster5.title("Biljettförsäljning för EN biograf.")
            fonster5.geometry("350x200")

            for p in personer:
                bio1.append(salda1.get())
                print(bio1)
```

Comment: @CoolCloud here is the whole code

Comment: Are you sure, you know how to use classes? I would recommend to do this without classes if your not familiar with OOP. It might also be better to include in pictures of your problems and so on.

Comment: @CoolCloud I also have an option in my main menu (class Huvudmeny) for ONE cinema. That part is working the way I want it to and therefore I left it out. I figure, since it is two different menu options, It's better to place them in a class?

Comment: @CoolCloud if you want to I can send my whole program instead.

Comment: I think if you re write the code without using classes, you might notice whats wrong

Comment: We don't need or want the whole code. You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: @CoolCloud. Now it stores the last three inputs!! thank you for your help. I think I might understand how to do it now!! :)

Comment: @BryanOakley it was specifically requested. :) I know you're not supposed to.